# fatal error LNK1104 cannot open file C:\users\user\documents\visual.obj

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I get a "fatal error LNK1104 cannot open file C:\users\user\documents\visual.obj" whenever I want to compile my project on Visual Studio 2008.

my project uses a .lib file that I created.

can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Thanks , guyz.

I've found the solution to my problem.
I had to add quotes around the path to my .lib file in Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies .

Attilah.

Comment: Good catch, just hit this error trying to setup Boost.Test on a static library project.

Comment: I had to move the project directory to C:\ and solved my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks , guyz. I've found the solution to my problem. I had to add quotes around the path to my .lib file in Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the directory C:\users\user\documents\ exists and that you have read/write access to it.

Answer (score 0):

With this http://www.google.de/search?q=visual+studio+2008+LNK1104 I found this answer by http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/user?user=einaros.

> You need to add the DirectX library folder to Visual Studio's search path. See the "Directories" settings under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions. Otherwise the linker will not know where to find d3dx9.lib.